# JQuery / Font Awesome - Star rating default value

Tags: jquery, html, css, font-awesome

The Scenario:

Basically, I have a system that has the ability for users to rate different products (Using Laravel) and I get given a number, an average which then populates the stars. The ratings are displayed on the "Product Listing" page so there will be multiple products on that page.

What I want to do:

I want to be able to pass a variable through the div which populates the stars on page load. I have tried the following:

```
<span class="rating" rating="3">
  <span class="star "></span>
  <span class="star "></span>
  <span class="star"></span>
  <span class="star"></span>
  <span class="star"></span>
</span>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.rating').each(function (event) {

  var rating = $(this).attr('rating');

  for(var i = 0; (i < rating); i++)
  {
        $('.rating span.star').eq(i).addClass('filled');
  }

});
```

But the issue is that the stars are populated in the wrong areas. And also, when there is another product, it just takes the last product and their star rating and ignores the rest.

A live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/qes0tgrt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for making stars in right direction you need to change the `.rating` class to:

```
.rating {
       unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
       direction:ltr;
       font-size:30px;
}
```

add these classes for half star :

```
span.star.half-filled:before{
    content: "\f089";
    color:#e3cf7a;
}
span.star.half-filled:after{
    content: "\f006";
    color:#e3cf7a;
    margin-left:-20px;
}
```

and script look likes this:

```
$('.rating').each(function (event) {
   var rating = $(this).attr('rating');
   for(var i = 0; (i < rating); i++)
   {
      $(this).find('span.star').eq(i).addClass('filled');
   }
   //if rating has decimal places means its a half star
   if(rating % 1 > 0)
      $(this).find('span.star').eq(i - 1).addClass('half-filled');
});
```

and finally for half star use rating attribute like this:

```
<span class="rating" rating="2.5">
```

**Updated** working sample : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsh85/qes0tgrt/11/)

Comment: Thanks, thats great! Just a slight note, any ideas on how to half fill it? E.g. rating of 1.5 ?